# Is there a best practice limitation of how many items I should keep in a single DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am setting up a Serverless application for a system and I am wondering the following:

Say that my table handle Companies. Each Company can have Invoices. Each company has roughly 6-8000 Invoices. Say that I have 14 Companies, that results in roughly 112 000 items in my table.

Is it "okay" to handle it this way? I will only pay for each Get request I do, and I can query a lot of items into the same get request.

- I will not fetch every single item each time I write or get items.

So, is there a recommendation for how many items I should max have in a table? I could bake some items together, but I mainly want a general recommendation.

Comment: There are no limit as such, however there are certain guidelines/principle to follow. Item size including attributes should not cross 400 KB. Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no practical limit to the number of items you can have in a table. How many items each invoice is depends on your application's access patterns. You need to ask, what data does your app need, when does it need that data, and how large is the data, how often is the item updated. For example, if all the data in one item comes in under the 1Kb WCU and 4Kb RCU and you do not write to it often, and when you read it, you need all of the data in the item, then shove it in one item perhaps. If the data is larger, or part of it gets written to more often, then perhaps split it up.

An example might be a package tracking app. You have the initial information about the package, size, weight, source address, destination address, etc. That could be a lot of data. When that package enters a sorting facility it is checked in. Do you want to update that entire item you already wrote? Or do you just write an item that has the same PK (item collection), but a different SK and then the info that it made it to the sorting facility? When it leaves the sorting facility, you want to write to the DB that it left, which truck it was on, etc. Same questions.

Now when you need to present the shipping information by tracking ID number, the PK, you can do a query to DynamoDB and get the entire item collection for that tracking ID number. Therefore you get all items with that ID as your app presents much of that information on the tracking web site for the customer.

So again, it really depends on the app and your access patterns, but you want to TRY to only read and write the items your app needs, when you need them, how you need them, and no more...within reason (there is such a thing as over slicing your data). That is how, in my opinion, you will make a NoSQL database like DynamoDB be the most performant and most cost effective.

Comment: Thanks! As the question stated, the only thing I was asking for is if there are any practical limits to the amount of items in a dynamodb table. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo Db won't even notice 100K entries...

As mentioned by LifeOfPi, entries should be less than 400k.

The question indicates a distinct lack of understanding of what/why/how to use DDB.  I suggest you do some more learning.  The AWS Reinvent videos around DDB are quite useful.

In a standard RDBMS, you need to know the structure from the beginning.  Accessing that data is then very flexible.

DDB is the opposite, you need to understand how you'll need to access you data; the structure is not important.  You should end up with something like so:
[image]

For 100K items and for most applications, you may find Aurora serverless to be an easier fit for your needs; especially if you have complicated searching and/or sorting needs.